# what does this "snap-repair" error mean?

Tags: snap

And how do I fix it?

> snap-repair[17970]: error: cannot use snap-repair on a classic system

I find this 3-4 times per day in my syslog.

Comment: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/ubuntu-snapd-with-no-snaps-installed-firing-recurring-hids-alerts/1997/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue as stated by @MichaelBay and the solution for now till a proper fix is done is:

```
sudo systemctl stop snap-repair.timer
sudo systemctl disable snap-repair.timer
```

So it does not come back after a reboot, which I assume it would, this kills the link

```
sudo systemctl stop snapd
sudo systemctl disable snapd
```

If you have need for snapd, don't run the latter two commands.

*Solution provided by online user `jdyke` from source link*

Source:

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/ubuntu-snapd-with-no-snaps-installed-firing-recurring-hids-alerts/1997/6